# Forward declarations of unnamed struct

Tags: c++, c, struct, typedef, forward-declaration

**Bounty question:** So, these two `Foo`s aren't the same thing. Fine. The second form is given in a library. *How do I forward-declare it given that I can't change it?*

---

I always thought C and C++ allowed repeated declarations provided that there were no repeated definitions. Then I came across this problem when trying to write C++ code which extends a C library.

```
struct Foo;
typedef struct {} Foo;
```

This gives the following error:

> 'struct Foo' has a previous declaration as 'struct Foo'

I want to forward-declare, darn it! What's wrong here?

Comment: What's the compiler? Also, maybe the empty declaration is bothering it?

Comment: There's no language called "C/C++", *especially* in the context of structs. There are too many alleged C++ writers to litter "struct" over their code like it was 1989.

Comment: @Kerrek there's nothing wrong with `struct` in C++ code, I use it to indicate I am writing an unencapsulated POD type.

Comment: @spraff: I think Kerrek is referring to the C "idiom" of not hiding `struct`s behind a `typedef`, instead doing things like void `foo(struct MyStruct *p);`.

Comment: @Oli: Exactly. And things like typedef definitions, `typedef struct Foo { /* ... /* } Foo;`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

typedef-ing anonymous struct is a practice that pre-dates C++03 and is mainly oriented to retain compatibility with pre-C99 compilers.

Given that this is 2011, and that both C++ and C are changed, I wonder why there is no more up-to-date version of such a library!

If it is not in development anymore, you cannot "leave", but just "survive" and change it is the way to do that.
If still in deployment, submit the issue to the development team.

If you need a workaround, consider that struct can inherit.
So, write a forward declaration like

```
struct MyFoo;
```

and define it as

```
#include "old_library.h"
struct MyFoo: public Foo {};
```

And in all your code, forget about `Foo` and always use `MyFoo`.

Comment: In a similar situation, I have a legacy C header with something like
== old_library.h ==
typedef struct { int data; } Foo;
== /old_library.h ==
I use it in a C++ class of my own, as parameter for a private method:

class C {
  void run(Foo *ds);
  ...
}

To avoid #include "old_library.h" from C.hpp, I use the following forward declaration:

class C {
  struct Foo;
  void run(Foo *ds);
  ...
}

and in C.cpp I have the following statements:

extern "C" {
#include "old_library.h"
}
struct C::Foo : public ::Foo {};

This way, I use C::Foo instead of Foo transparently, and don't need a MyFoo!

Comment: "Given that this is 2011, and that both C++ and C are changed, I wonder why there is no more up-to-date version of such a library!"
Likely because the de facto standard compiler for C and C++ code on Windows, MSVC++, now in 2014 still does not support C99 and is unlikely to support it anytime soon.

Comment: @Kaiserludi Even in C99, if you just declared a `struct` in C++ style, then you have  use keyword `struct` everywhere before its name  in function prototypes, which `typedef` allows to avoid.

Answer (score 40):

You're declaring two different entities with the same name. The first, `struct Foo`, is a struct named `Foo`. The second is an alias for an *anonymous* struct.

If you do instead:

```
struct Foo;
struct Foo {};
```

It works, because you're declaring a struct named `Foo` in both situations.

You cannot forward declare anonymous structs. You're left with two choices: include the whole definition, or change the header and name the struct.

Comment: For the OP, you also cannot forward-declare typedefs.

Answer (score 14):

In a similar situation, I have a legacy C header with something like

```
== old_library.h ==
typedef struct { int data; } Foo;
== /old_library.h ==
```

I use it in a C++ class of my own, as parameter for a private method:

```
class C {
  void run(Foo *ds);
  ...
}
```

To avoid #include "old_library.h" from C.hpp, I use the following forward declaration:

```
class C {
  struct Foo;
  void run(Foo *ds);
  ...
}
```

and in C.cpp I have the following statements:

```
extern "C" {
#include "old_library.h"
}
struct C::Foo : public ::Foo {};
```

This way, I use C::Foo instead of Foo transparently, and don't need a MyFoo!

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to typedef structs in C++:

```
struct Foo;     // Forward declaration

struct Foo 
{

}; // Definition
```

If you want to call it just `Foo` instead of `struct Foo` in C, you *do* need the typedef, which can also be done in different ways:

```
struct Foo;     /* Forward declaration */

struct Foo /* The name is needed here */
{

}; /* Definition */
typedef struct Foo Foo;  /* typedef */
```

or

```
struct Foo;     /* Forward declaration */

typedef struct Foo /* The name is needed here */
{

} Foo; /* Definition and typedef combined */
```

You can of course use the form `struct Foo` in both C and C++.

Comment: In C, you don't *need* the typedef; you can refer to the type as `struct Foo`.  (Some of us prefer to do it that way.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: The separate typedef can also be done BEFORE the definition of the struct as a forward declaration.

Answer (score 5):

Your forward declaration declares that there will be a `struct` called `Foo`.

Your second declaration is of a `typedef` called `Foo`.  These are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

For a forward declaration of a typedef, you need to refer to the thing that is being typedeffed, so like:

```
struct foo;
typedef foo bar;
class foo{};
```

Since you want to forward declare an anonymous struct, you can neither give it a name in the forward declaration of the original entity, nor can you refer to it when typedefing it. The "logical" syntax would be:

```
struct ;
typedef bar;
class {};
```

But since this is obviously not possible, you can not forward declare anonymous structs.

To go standardese, lets have a look at 9.1-2:

> A declaration consisting solely of class-key identifier; is either a
>   redeclaration of the name in the current scope or a forward
>   declaration of the identifier as a class name. It introduces the class
>   name into the current scope.

No identifier, no forward declaration.

Bottom line of this: avoid anonymous structs unless they give you an advantage that you really need.

Comment: Sometimes the anonymous structs come with legacy headers, and it's a bad idea to mess with some old 3rd party library headers.

The solution dates back to 2001 [http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/4f1aa831b91266b/96fcc9007e24c662]: you cannot forward declare from an unnamed struct "as is", but you can inherit from it, and forward declare your derived class!

Answer (score 2):

Your specific compiler may make a difference here.

Using MinGW GCC 3.4.5, both declarations compile with no errors or warnings (using `-Wall`)

```
struct Foo;
typedef struct {} Foo;
```

and

```
struct Foo;
typedef struct Foo {} Foo;
```

Is it possible a forward-declaration already exists inside the library? For instance, to allow a circular pointer:

```
struct Foo;
typedef struct Foo {
    struct Foo *fooPtr;
} Foo;
```

If this already exists within the library headers, it would cause the error you describe.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, simply change your `typedef` to,

```
typedef struct Foo {} Foo;
              ^^^^^
```

There is no harm and it will still compatible in both C & C++. Now you can forward declare it.

[Note: If you still insist on on not touching the `typedef` at all then here is the *dirty trick*.

```
struct Foo;
#define struct struct Foo
#include"Foo.h"  // contains typedef struct {} Foo;
#undef struct
```

This will work, only if `Foo.h` contains only 1 `struct` declaration. I **don't recommend** it.]

Comment: I agree, with the minor change that I'd use: `typedef struct Foo_struct {} Foo;` which avoids name conflicts in some of the older C compilers and is generally more clear when trying to figure out weird compile errors (is it the struct or the typedef that's failing sorts of things, C++ compilers don't have this issue but I think it's still considered good form).

Answer (score 1):

I think I recently ran into the same problem as the original poster, and have resolved it as below:

I am writing a wrapper around a third-party provided API defined as:

Foo.h:

```
typedef struct _foo 
{
    int i;
} Foo;

Foo* MakeFoo();
int UseFoo(Foo* foo);
```

My wrapper needs to have Foo as a member, but I don't want to expose Foo to all consumers of my wrapper.

UberFoo.h:

```
#pragma once

struct _foo;  // forward declare the actual type _foo, not the typedef Foo

class UberFoo
{
public:
    UberFoo();
    int GetAnswer();
private:
    _foo* f;
};
```

UberFoo.cpp:

```
#include "UberFoo.h"
#include "Foo.h"

UberFoo::UberFoo()
{
    this->f = MakeFoo();
}

int UberFoo::GetAnswer()
{
    return UseFoo(f);
}
```

Now, the consumers of my class can instantiate it without having access to the actual definition of _foo/Foo.  This would also work if I needed to pass pointers to _foo as parameters or return them from functions as well as having a member _foo.

main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "UberFoo.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    UberFoo u;
    printf( "The Answer = %d\n", u.GetAnswer());
    return 0;
}
```

The trick here was to forward declare the actual struct type, not the typedef'd name.  Note that it is critical that the struct not be anonymous, as is common in older C code:

```
typedef struct // the actual struct type underlying the typedef is anonymous here
{
    int i;
} ThisWontWork;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just avoid forward decl.

If the second definition was in a header file, you could include the header file first in your  C++ header file. To make C++ think it as C header, embracing #include with  `extern "C" {` and `}` must be suffice in most case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't forward declare it, since its unnamed. Its an unnamed struct, for which Foo is a typedef.

Comment: The idea dates back to 2001 [http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/4f1aa831b91266b/96fcc9007e24c662]: you cannot forward declare from an unnamed struct "as is", but you can inherit from it, and forward declare your derived class!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to typedef a previously used name. The statement is perfectly valid, only you need to use a different name.

```
struct Foo; // Forward declaration of struct Foo
typedef struct {} anotherFoo; // Another structure typedefed
struct Foo {
 // Variables
}; // Definition of the forward declared Foo.
```

Note that the typedef cannot be used in the same name.