# Forward declaring a typedef of an unnamed struct

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forward declarations of unnamed struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256436/forward-declarations-of-unnamed-struct)

If I have

```
typedef struct tagPAGERANGE
{
    int iFirstPage;
    int iLastPage;
} PAGERANGE;
```

I can forward declare it that way

```
struct tagPAGERANGE;
typedef struct tagPAGERANGE PAGERANGE;
```

But what I have is

```
typedef struct
{
    int iFirstPage;
    int iLastPage;
} PAGERANGE;
```

I'm not sure how I can do it. I only want to hold a pointer to this struct. Right now I'm stuck with either including a rather substantial header, or duplicating the definition of the struct.

Comment: Doesn't look much like C++. Why did you tag it with "C++" tag?

Comment: What's wrong with naming the struct?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Which language are you asking about?

Comment: @Griwes The project it comes from is a C++ project. It compiles in C++.

Comment: @mydogisbox The header file is from a library.

Comment: @Robᵩ I'll remove any of the 2 tags, just choose one. My project is a C++ project, so I'll remove the C tag.

Comment: Who the heck voted to close as not a real question? Just because the answer is "it's not possible" it doesn't make it any less valid.

Comment: Yeah, it is a real question, but it's also a dup.

Comment: @mydogisbox I actually searched for 3-4 minutes before asking the quesiton but couldn't find anything unnamed structs. Maybe I wasn't using the best search terms. But I really am not willing to search for 1 hour before gathering courage to ask a question.

Comment: @satuon Nothing wrong with posting a dup.  It just gets closed.

Comment: @satuon, I meant that `typedef struct XXX {...} YYY;` is de facto C; in C++, you would just do `struct YYY {};` and be done with it. So there is really no place for "C++" tag here.

Comment: the question is how to get the c++ compiler to accept this. coding style aside.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's impossible. You can only declare named structs.

Think about what identifies a struct that doesn't have a name, and how do you tell the compiler that it's that struct you want. If it doesn't have a name, it's identified by its members, so you need to provide members — i.e. define it. Therefore, you can't *just* declare it — you don't have a luxury of an identifier other than the definition itself.

Comment: there is a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7304634/347508

Answer (score 2):

Since this is used in a C++ code, just get rid of the typedefs altogether, they are unnecessary and bad style in C++.

The real solution is to just use named structs:

```
struct foo; // forward declaration

struct foo {
    // … implementation
};
```

The typedefs are not useful.

Comment: The header file that uses those typedefs is not mine, and it's designed to work in both C and C++.

Comment: @satuon In that case see the duplicate question. As the cat said, this is simply not possible but the other question shows a (hideous) workaround.